# how to use magma to find the rank of the elliptic curve

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, magma

I am trying to find as much as possible of elliptic curves in Magma. What is the code for finding the rank of elliptic curve in Magma? I want to write a for loop for the curve $y^2=y^3+ax^2+bx+c$ for ($-30 <a,b<30$). Could someone help me with the code?

Comment: https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1458#16609

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the following code:

${\tt P<x>:=PolynomialRing(RationalField());\\
for \,\,a \,\,in\,\, [-30..30]\,\, do\\
for \,\,b \,\,in\,\, [-30..30]\,\, do\\
for \,\,c \,\,in\,\, [-30..30]\,\, do\\
if \,\,Discriminant(x^3+a*x^2+b*x+c) \,\,ne\,\, 0 \,\,then\\
E:=EllipticCurve([0,a,0,b,c]);\\
print\,\, E,Rank(E);\\
end\,\, if;\\
end\,\, for;\\
end\,\, for;\\
end\,\, for;}$

Comment: Does this give the rank, or just the analytic rank?